# Python 2.7: Convert one line into lines of 260 characters and remove all character before '_' in each line

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, lines, readlines

I must convert infile into lines of 260 characters and than remove all the content before (including the character) '_'

I have been looking around for hours now and found a way to convert to 260 characters.

```
lines = infile.readlines()
[line[i:i+n] for i in lines(0, len(line), 640)]
```

and found a lot of examples wrt removing characters from string or all characters after an argument.

Please help me out here...

Comment: If you want to manipulate whole words instead of characters only, have a look at `textwrap`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = infile.readlines()
[line[i:i+n] for i in lines(0, len(line), 640)]
line.split("_")[1]
```